# Problem with ElevatedButton with border from left and right

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this codes for ElevatedButton to showe user button with image:

```
return Container(
  padding: paddingsize, // Adjust padding here
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fixedSize: const Size(150, 60),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      elevation: 0, // Remove padding
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Image(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: AssetImage(imagepath),
    ),
  ),
);
```

but i see this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f46AE.png)

as you could see i have border from left and right! how could i remove them?

i want to see result without any border.

Comment: What is `paddingsize`?

Comment: or dont use an image, the image itself just looks like a background color, icon and text. would be simpler and easier to manage if you create that in flutter, with the method Naslausky provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have full control over how the button looks you need to create yourself a custom widget:

```dart
GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: 150,
                  height: 60,
                  child: Image(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(imagepath),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  print("Your action goes here");
                })
```

Comment: thanks, and now how could i navigate my program to another page when photo is clicked?

Comment: ok i understood, i could use ;  Navigator.push